# turn around or travel around

Tags: word-choice

The earth takes a year to **turn around** the sun one time.
The earth takes a year to **travel around** the sun one time.

Which is suitable, **turn around** or **travel around?**
 I found **turn around** on this link.
http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=23&ved=0ahUKEwjf7O3u2cvQAhVEPY8KHQlXCE8QFgh4MBY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.wordreference.com%2Fthreads%2Fthe-earth-is-turning-around-the-sun.694578%2F&usg=AFQjCNFxG5MM7-aMbFd4Vn_JrB_G7-9uww
https://books.google.com/books?id=3PGLAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA25&dq=%22turn+around+the+sun%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjD8d7h28vQAhXKOI8KHUORASEQ6AEIOjAG

Comment: Since the Earth *turns* on its own axis, *travel around* might be better (or simply *orbit*).

Comment: You can also say, "The earth _revolves_ around the sun."

Answer (score 1):

The technical (astronomical) terms are: [to rotate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rotate) and [to revolve](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/revolve)

The main difference between the two is the position of the axis: through the object, or outside the object.

---

In the case of your question, it is not about using the most scientific terms, so the following are OK:

> The earth takes a year to **rotate** around the sun one time.

(although still not the best)

> The earth takes a year to **travel** around the sun one time.

(it is just fine )

The next two are the most correct:

> - The earth takes a year to **revolve** around the sun one time.
> - The earth takes a year to **orbit** around the sun one time.

---

A professional astronomer might have additional ideas, but I am not one of them.

Note: "revolve" is the most "complicated" word, and might not be understood by any average Joe, so be careful to know your audience when you use it.

Answer (score -1):

According to the meaning of words many possibilities can exist:

The earth **turns** around the sun.

- **to turn** - move or cause to move in a circular direction wholly or partly around an axis or point.

The earth **travels** around the sun.

- **to travel** - (of an object or radiation) move, typically in a constant or predictable way.

The earth **goes** around the sun.

- **to go** - move from one place to another; travel. To be in the process of moving.

The earth **orbits** the sun.

- **to orbit** - the regularly repeated elliptical course of a celestial object or spacecraft about a star or planet.

> Notice no **around** needed.

The earth **revolves** around the sun.

- **to revolve** - move in a circle on a central axis, move in a circular orbit around.

The earth **moves** around the sun.

- **to move** - go in a specified direction or manner; change position.

Still the best two choices I would stick to are: **travels**, **revolves**, **goes** and **orbits**.

Comment: You should change _rotate_ to _revolve_ in this answer; [_rotate_ is not the right word to used for this](https://www.google.com/search?q=difference+between+revolving+and+rotating). I also don't think _turns_ is a very good choice here.

Comment: I agree, considering that **revolve** is a better term and closer to **orbit**, yet **rotate** can have the same meaning but am not completely sure if it's applicable here.

Comment: SovereignSun: According to Ngram both **"Earth rotates around the sun"** and **"Earth revolves around the sun"**  are very popular.

Comment: [According to Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=earth+rotates+around+the+sun%2C+earth+revolves+around+the+sun&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) the latter is much more popular than the former.

Comment: You are right but it does exist. Bad English?

Comment: Less accurate English.